# Apache2: How can I get Apache2 to not respond?

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, blocking

I didn't find a way but it can't be so hard : How make Apache2 Listen a port but not responding.

My VH:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName catchall
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't want to respond 403 or another status... I want the connexion failed.

Why ? Just because I have an other VH on the same port but wich is responding for a domain and I can't have this IP connection.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you *should* just be able to block the outgoing port through iptables with something along the lines of:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 403 -j DROP
```

Just configure it to listen, and then on response its outgoing packet *should* be dropped silently. 
This rule would have to be before any outgoing rule that might apply that might include the

```
"--state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT"
```

Line.

More information can be found here: http://linuxconfig.org/collection-of-basic-linux-firewall-iptables-rules"